# Increment value base on separator row

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to be able to increment a value when a "separator row" is reached.

As an example; zero is the separator row.

```
GROUP_ID
--------
1
1
1
0 
1
1
0
1
1
1
```

What I want is:

```
GROUP_ID
--------
1
1
1
0 
2
2
0
3
3
3
```

Of course outlier scenarios like starting with zero, or consecutive zeros can exist also.  I though NTILE might be useful as it has a similar idea of creating buckets.

```
select START_DATE, END_DATE, DTEDIF, GROUP_ID
  FROM (select START_DATE,
               END_DATE,
               DTEDIF,
               (CASE
                 WHEN DTEDIF <= 24 THEN
                  1
                 ELSE
                  0
               END) GROUP_ID

          FROM (select START_DATE,
                       END_DATE,
                       MONTHS_BETWEEN(END_DATE, START_DATE) as DTEDIF
                  from (select start_date,
                               LEAD(start_date, 1) OVER(order by start_date) as END_DATE
                          from (select sysdate start_date
                                  from dual
                                union all
                                select add_months(sysdate, 12) dt
                                  from dual --12
                                union all
                                select add_months(sysdate, 22) dt
                                  from dual --10
                                union all
                                select add_months(sysdate, 40) dt
                                  from dual --18
                                union all
                                select add_months(sysdate, 68) dt
                                  from dual --28
                                union all
                                select add_months(sysdate, 70) dt
                                  from dual --18
                                union all
                                select add_months(sysdate, 88) dt
                                  from dual --18
                                union all
                                select add_months(sysdate, 118) dt
                                  from dual --30
                                ))));
```

Comment: This question cannot be answered unless there exist one or more columns which provides the _ordering_ appearing in your source table.

Comment: @user2296256 . . . The question is quite clear.  I have no idea what the query has to do with it.  Perhaps you should ask *another* question if what you want to know is really about that query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:  Count the number of zeros before each row:

```
select t.*,
       (case when group_id = 0 then group_id
             else sum(case when group_id = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by <ordering column>)
        end) as new_group_id
from t;
```

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So your question requires a separate column to represent the ordering of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using combination of `lag` and `sum` analytical function.

I consider that there is ordering column available with name id.

```
Select group_id, 
       Sum(case when coalesce(lag_group_id,0) then 1 else 0 end) 
       over(order by id) as your_result from
(Select id, 
        group_id, 
        lag(group_id) over (order by id) as lag_group_id 
   from your_table)
```

Cheers!!